# Any work around to sophos

Tags: security

Sophos is an app that let's you put passwords on apps (among other things). Is there a work around to access the apps?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yeah! By uninstalling the app (here Sophos) provided that the app is not set to Device Administrator. You should know the password anyways if the app is acting like Device Administrator.

Comment: Well my dad put sophos on my phone so I don't know the password.